# ¿Còmo puedo hacer un Insert en dos tablas al mismo tiempo con una sola acción en mi controlador?

Tags: html, c#, mvc, entity-framework-6

Lo que sucede es que tengo dos tablas:
`Cotizaciones` y `CotizacionesProductos`.

En mi tabla cotizaciones guardo la información de productos cotizados, los cuales pueden ser varios productos en una cotización, mi idea fue guardar esta información de productos cotizados en otra tabla llamada `CotizacionesProductos`, donde únicamente quiero guardar el `ID` de la cotización y el `ID` del producto cotizado. La finalidad de esto es que al momento de guardar mi cotización, la tabla `CotizaciónProducto` también se llene y quede algo mas o menos así:

> CotizaciónProducto:
>
> CotizaciónID = 1
>
> ProductoId = 12

Mi código en el controlador es el siguiente:

```
[HttpPost]

        public ActionResult Insert(Cotizaciones model)
        {
            {
                var rh = _cotizacionService.Insert(model);
                if (rh.Response)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
            }

            return View(model);
        }
```

y mi código en el servicio es el siguiente:

```
public ResponseHelper Insert(Cotizaciones model)
        {
            var rh = new ResponseHelper();

            try
            {
                using (var ctx = _dbContextScopeFactory.Create())
                {

                    _cotizacionesRepository.Insert(model);

                    ctx.SaveChanges();
                    rh.SetResponse(true);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                logger.Error(e.Message);
            }

            return rh;
        }
```

Gracias de antemano por su ayuda.

Comment: edita por favor y agrega el código como texto y no como imagen

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto, siempre.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Igual mas alla de todo, no se entiende que estas preguntando. Porque no haces directamente los dos insert? cual es el problema puntual?

Comment: ya modifiqué mi pregunta tratando de ser lo mas explícito posible. Gracias por la sugerencia, soy nuevo aquí

Comment: Hola @JuanEspinoza , como tienes las tablas de `SQL` en `Cotizaciones` solo guardas la info y en `CotizacionesProductos` tienes el id de `Cotizaciones` como foranea ?

Comment: Exactamente así  amigo, en la tabla CotizacionesProducto solo tengo el id de cotizaciones como CotizacionesId y el otro campo es ProductoId que guardaría el Id del producto cotizado.

Comment: Ok, lo que tienes que hacer es realizar primero el registro de la tabla cotización y con ese id realizar el otro proceso , Muéstrame como estas recorriendo la lista de cotización productos, cuando los recorras le asignas el id de la cotización a la que corresponde después de realizar el registro

Comment: Mejor dicho tienes tres tablas una `Cotizaciones` , `Productos` y tienes una tabla de relación `CotizacionProductos` en la cual agregas el `idCotizacion` y `IdProducto` ?????